# why this String desc variable not get inserted to the database in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am a newbie to `hibernate` framework. I following a tutorial series available on the this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yv2xctJxE-w). Here is my `model class`

```
package kasun.hibernate.moreAnnotations;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity 
@Table(name="UserDetailsMoreAnn")
public class UserDetailsMoreAnnotations {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private Date date;
    private String desc;

    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
//  public String getDesc() {
//      return desc;
//  }
//  public void setDesc(String desc) {
//      this.desc = desc;
//  }





}
```

and this is my `Service method`

```
package kasun.hibernate.moreAnnotations;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class ServiceMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetailsMoreAnnotations objct= new UserDetailsMoreAnnotations();
        objct.setName("Kalanka");
        objct.setId(7);
        objct.setAddress("Kuliyapitiya");
        objct.setDate(new Date());      // provide the current date
//      objct.setDesc("Younger Brother");



        SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session= sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(objct);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

and this is my `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!-- ~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java ~ ~ License: 
    GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later. ~ See the 
    lgpl.txt file in the root directory or <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html>. -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <!-- <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsq/ldb.jdbcDriver</property> 
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/TestDB</property> -->

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateTesting1</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>



        <!-- 5) for the kasun.hibernate.moreAnnotations package -->
        <mapping class="kasun.hibernate.moreAnnotations.UserDetailsMoreAnnotations" />




    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Above code runs without errors. The problem I encounter is that when I uncomment the lines

```
   public String getDesc() {
            return desc;
    }
        public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
        }
```

in my `model class` and set a value to `desc` by uncommenting the line 
`objct.setDesc("Younger Brother");` in the `Service Method`

I got a error as `Unable to execute command [alter table UserDetailsMoreAnn add column desc varchar(255)]` and it says that `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc varchar(255)' at line 1`. What I am doing wrong? Can anyone help me to fix this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DESC` is a reserved keyword in MySQL and cannot be used for field name.  Try renaming to `Description` or something. :)

You can also annotate the field, but must use brackets or escaped quotes:

`@Column(name = "[DESC]")
    public String getDesc() {`

or

`@Column(name = "\"DESC\"")
    public String getDesc() {`

list of reserved words for MySQL 5.7: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: All reserved keyword in MySQL can be used with help of back tick symbol.

Answer (score 0):

`desc` is keyword in sql. You should use back tick character(`).

Here i cannot use back tick since stack overflow take it as code sample.

So here i use single quotes. 'desc' varchar(255) instead of desc varchar(255) in database. Using back tick symbol, we can use all reserved keyword in mysql

For back tick, refer https://superuser.com/questions/254076/how-do-i-type-the-tick-and-backtick-characters-on-windows

For entity mapping, refer http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-use-database-reserved-keyword-in-hibernate/

Comment: What is a back tick character

Comment: See my updated answer. See above the tab button in keyboard

Comment: True, but the Java class method may not use backticks in the name, forcing extra work to map to a database column. Better to rename the column.

Comment: @Isaac Hanson: Java doesn't complain when we use keyword in sql. If db doesn't have then only it will not compile i think.

Comment: @lokesh not sure I understand what you are saying. Can you back-quote a keyword and hibernate will bind the column without additional mapping annotations? Looks like OP is defining his object model first and generating the schema

Comment: Well, that is additional mapping.  But, that is cool.  I didn't know hibernate would add the back-quotes to column name annotations.

Comment: @lokesh Not true it turns out.  That causes an exception too.  See edit to my answer above.